# Add modules in webpack runtime code as they are required by all entry points

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have certain modules such as Modernizr which I would like to be in the 'runtime' file of webpack, since it's important that these are loaded ASAP. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add such modules as Webpack puts them into a seperate asset everytime. Is there a way to add certain modules in to the `runtime.js` file?

After a few hours I ended up with the following file, however, it remains a mystery to me as to how I can add modules into the runtime.js file.

```
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        vendor: './js/vendor.js',
        global: './js/global.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            $: "jquery/src/jquery",
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        },
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: true,
            extractComments: '/@extract/i',
            parallel: 6
        })]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                }
            },
        }]
    }
};
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the 'runtime' entry to add things to the runtime chunk.